# Is it ok to ask about video games?

Tags: discussion

Kind of 2 questions here, just one is more specific.

1. Is it ok to ask for video game recommendations as long as I give enough criteria for it to be answerable?
2. If so, would asking about **wii** games follow the rules, or are they not considered software?

Thanks for the help, I just wanted to check before posting.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for checking before posting.

The answer to your first question is a definite "YES"!  No problem at all, and actually, quite encouraged. :)

My personal answer to your second question is "I don't know".  Personally, it's fine by me, since it is definitely software, but I don't know how other community members feel about it.

So, let's give it a little time and see what others think (I'm responding 10 minutes after you posted your question).

Enjoy your wii.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer!  It's great that the first question is solved, and I'm in no hurry so I'll definitely wait a while to hear what others think regarding the second.  Have a great day!

Comment: You're quite welcome.  And thank you... you too!

Comment: Hey, @RockPaperLz- Mask it or Casket , there hasn't been any responses, or many views yet, if you like you could message some other mods to get there opinions, or I could ask a question and link this post for discussion if anyone disagrees with the question, does that sound good?  I definitely can wait longer if u prefer, but from my experience at this stage the likelyhood of more answers can be pretty low since a mod has already responded.  thnx.

Comment: @Millard If it works for you, I think it would be time-efficient for you post a single question asking for a related software recommendation you seek.  If it gets complaints, you can refer them to this QA, so the community can discuss.  Overall, I prefer to not have us moderators setting the guidelines, but let the community come together to build the community we want to see.

Comment: Hi, RockPaperLz- Mask it or Casket, I noticed that there is an existing tag for the wii, so I have posted the question, and I have gotten no complaints, so I think we are good.  Also, I really respect your desire for the community to decide, thanks!

Comment: You're welcome, and I hope you get some helpful answers!